Best threshold to use when recognising faces using mobilefacenet model in Flutter (Maximum Euclid Distance)
Currently I'm developing a attendance system using flutter with tensorflow and google mlkit integration. So far everything works fine but comparing face giving wrong information because the detected faces will return nearest possible face information. I'm implementing this for Sri Lankan Student (mostly brown skin) better if this works for majority.
My function for recognize faces are given below.
Calculation Part
  findNearest(List<double> emb) {
    Pair pair = Pair("Unknown", -5);
    for (MapEntry<String, Recognition> item in registered.entries) {
      final String name = item.key;
      List<double> knownEmb = item.value.embeddings;
      double distance = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < emb.length; i++) {
        double diff = emb[i] - knownEmb[i];
        distance += diff * diff;
      }
      distance = sqrt(distance);
      if (pair.distance == -5 || distance < pair.distance) {
        pair.distance = distance;
        pair.name = name;
      }
    }
    return pair;
  }

Execution Part
Here 1.25 is the threshold I used but still returning wrong face info
    faces = await faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);

    for (Face face in faces) {
      final Rect boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
      print("Bounding Box: ${boundingBox.toString()}");

      num left = boundingBox.left < 0 ? 0 : boundingBox.left;
      num top = boundingBox.top < 0 ? 0 : boundingBox.top;
      num right =
          boundingBox.right > image.width - 1 ? image.width : boundingBox.right;
      num bottom = boundingBox.bottom > image.height - 1
          ? image.height
          : boundingBox.bottom;

      num width = right - left;
      num height = bottom - top;

      // final bytes = _image!.readAsBytesSync();
      img.Image? faceImg = img.decodeImage(_image!.readAsBytesSync());

      img.Image? croppedFace = img.copyCrop(faceImg!,
          x: left.toInt(),
          y: top.toInt(),
          width: width.toInt(),
          height: height.toInt());

      Recognition recognition = recognizer.recognize(croppedFace, boundingBox);
      if (recognition.distance > 1.25) {
        recognition.name = "Unknown";
      }
      recognitions.add(recognition);
      print("Recognized Faces ${recognition.name}");
    }

